# Is it possible to insert a HERE XYZ map into an Android Studio project?

Tags: java, android, sdk, here-api

I decided to create a map with the new Here Maps XYZ Studio tool (which is still in Beta) and i was wondering if i can insert that map into my current Android Studio project.

I believe that right now, working with the XYZ Studio in an Android environment isn't covered yet but i read it is possible to insert standard Java into Android Studio after a bit of coding.

Basically, there is a URL and an Embed code given for the map and i wanted to ask if it is possible to use one of them and insert it into the fragment holder in Android Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by adding a WebView component in your activity_main.xml.

```
 <WebView
    android:id="@+id/xyzfragment"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Then, in the MainActivity class, just after the line

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Add the code below to initialize the webView and load the URL of the published map

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.xyzfragment);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("Enter_the_URL_of_your_published_map");
```

You will need to enable JavaScript as it is disabled by default.

For a detailed answer, you can check this tutorial: https://www.journaldev.com/9333/android-webview-example-tutorial